# How to link to a formula of another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets.

Sheet1:

```
  A     B     C
1 "x"  "y"   "z"
2
3    =A1&C1
```

Therefore here, B3 displays "xz"

Sheet2:

```
  A     B     C
1 "a"  "b"   "c"
2
3    =[MY QUESTION]
```

Now, I would like to link cell B3 in Sheet2 to cell B3 in Sheet1, so that when I change the value of `B3 in Sheet1` to `=A1&B1` then cell `B3 in Sheet2` displays "ab". If I change `B3 in Sheet1` to `=A1`, I want the `B3 in Sheet2` to display "a".

Is it possible to read the formula from another cell? Without any VBA and change watchers.

Comment: If you have *Excel 2013* you can use the **FORMULATEXT()** function.

Comment: @pnuts It would look something like  =LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(Sheet1!$B$3),"=",""),1,""),"&",""))

Comment: @pnuts Since I have *Excel 2007,* I can only test this with the web app.

Comment: @pnuts Thanks for the investigation.......this is the first time I tried copying from the web app.....I will avoid it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider grouping Sheets 1 and 2 before making the change in B3 (on either sheet). But this relies on the relative positions being the same on both sheets ( - do remember to ungroup afterwards or you may be sorry!)